# How to install VirtualCloneDrive silently with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, popups, silent-install

```
.\SetupVirtualCloneDrive5450.exe /S
```

I wrote this command. Then, Windows Security popup came on screen. It asked me "install?" or "don't install?"
How can i install this programme silently with PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Start-process C:\SetupVirtualCloneDrive5450.exe -Argumentlist "/S" -wait
```